# How can I reference an outer table in a subquery for a self left join?

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join, correlated-subquery

With this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE BAR (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE FOO (id INT PRIMARY KEY, rank INT UNIQUE, fk INT, FOREIGN KEY (fk) REFERENCES Bar(id));

INSERT INTO BAR (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO BAR (id) VALUES (2);

-- sample values
INSERT INTO FOO (id, rank, fk) VALUES (1, 10, 1);
INSERT INTO FOO (id, rank, fk) VALUES (2, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO FOO (id, rank, fk) VALUES (3, 9, 2);
INSERT INTO FOO (id, rank, fk) VALUES (4, 5, 1);
INSERT INTO FOO (id, rank, fk) VALUES (5, 12, 1);
INSERT INTO FOO (id, rank, fk) VALUES (6, 14, 2);
```

How can I query for certain rows of `FOO` *and* the rows linked to the same row of `BAR` with the next highest `rank`? That is, I want to search for certain rows ("targets"), and for each target row I also want to find another row ("secondary"), such that secondary has the highest rank of all rows with `secondary.fk = target.fk` *and* `secondary.rank < target.rank`.

For example, if I target all rows (no where clause), I would expect this result:

```
TARGET_ID  TARGET_RANK  SECONDARY_ID  SECONDARY_RANK
---------  -----------  ------------  --------------
        1           10             4               5
        2            3          NULL            NULL
        3            9          NULL            NULL
        4            5             2               3
        5           12             1              10
        6           14             3               9
```

When the target row has `id` 2 or 3, there is no secondary row because no row has the same `fk` as the target row and a lower `rank`.

I tried this:

```
SELECT F1.id AS TARGET_ID, F1.rank as TARGET_RANK, F2.id AS SECONDARY_ID, F2.rank AS SECONDARY_RANK
FROM FOO F1
LEFT JOIN FOO F2 ON F2.rank = (SELECT MAX(S.rank)
                               FROM FOO S
                               WHERE S.fk = F1.fk
                                 AND S.rank < F1.rank);
```

...but I got `ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery`.

Next I tried this:

```
SELECT F1.id AS TARGET_ID, F1.rank AS TARGET_RANK, F2.id AS SECONDARY_ID, F2.rank AS SECONDARY_RANK
FROM FOO F1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT S1.rank, S1.fk
           FROM FOO S1
           WHERE S1.rank = (SELECT MAX(S2.rank)
                            FROM FOO S2
                            WHERE S2.rank < F1.rank
                              AND S2.fk = F1.fk)
           ) F2 ON F2.fk = F1.fk;
```

...but I got `ORA-00904: "F1"."FK": invalid identifier`.

Surely there's **some** way to do this in a single query?

Comment: The error you are getting is because you are referring to f1 in a subquery where f1 is not defined. Remember a subquery is a standalone query that cannot refer to rows that are not included in the subquery. I think I can rewrite for you, might take a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't like the subquery inside the temporary table. The trick is to left join all the secondary rows with `rank` less than the target's `rank`, then use the WHERE clause to filter out all but the max while being sure not to filter out target rows with no secondary.

```
select F1.id as TARGET_ID, F1.rank as TARGET_RANK, F2.id as SECOND_ID, F2.rank as SECOND_RANK
from FOO F1
left join FOO F2 on F1.fk = F2.fk and F2.rank < F1.rank
where F2.rank is null or F2.rank = (select max(S.rank)
                                    from FOO S
                                    where S.fk = F1.fk
                                      and S.rank < F1.rank);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [Analytic Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm)

```
select id, 
lead(rank) over (partition by fk order by rank) next_rank
lag(rank) over (partition by fk order by rank)  prev_rank
from foo
```

It is more efficient than self joins.

But if you want to torture your database, you may try

```
select id, 
(select min(f2.rank) from foo f2 where f2.fk = f1.fk and f2.rank >f1.rank) next_rank,
(select max(f2.rank) from foo f2 where f2.fk = f1.fk and f2.rank <f1.rank) prev_rank
from foo f1
```

Ok, I misunderstood what needs to be in output. Here is example:

```
select id, rank, prev_rank_id from (
select id, rank,
lag(id) over (partition by fk order by rank) prev_rank_id
from foo
)
where id in (1, 3)
```

Analitic functions are working on OUTPUT dataset. You need to wrap it into another select statement to limit your actual output.

Comment: Hmmm, haven't used analytic functions before. Based on the Oracle documentation it *sounds* like it would work, but I'm not really sure how to apply it to the case at hand. Could you provide an example equivalent to the two in the question (except working)?

Comment: analitic functions are not specific to Oracle, they are part of SQL standard. They are very powerful tool - so it is important to know how they are working. Out of noticeble databases only MySQL do not support them.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking they were Oracle only. Regarding your edit, for `id=3` it should be `9, NULL` because there is no row with `fk=2 and rank<9`. Likewise, for `id=1` the result is `10, 5` and *not* `10, 12`. I need the row with the same `fk` and the highest `rank` *less than the first row's* `rank`.

Comment: Cool, changing lead (next record) to lag (previous record)!

Comment: I get null when I try that with `where id in (1, 3)`. I'm still not sure we're talking about the same thing. I updated the question again to make sure there's no confusion. I don't want each row of the result to be based on the previous row, I want each row of the result to return data from two table rows, a target row and a secondary row which is determined by the target row.

Comment: with analytic functions you can't use WHERE on the same level. I'll update answer to illustrate that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select f1.rank f1rank, f2.rank as f2rank
from foo f1
left join foo f2 on f1.fk = f2.fk and f1.rank > f2.rank
```

This will return a row for each foo record that has another record in the same table (using fk to determine that) and is lower than the existing rank.  Now you just want the max(f2.rank) from there.  Turn above into a subquery and find the max

```
Select f1rank, max(f2rank) f2rank
from
(select f1.rank f1rank, f2.rank as f2rank
from foo f1
left join foo f2 on f1.fk = f2.fk and f1.rank > f2.rank) a
group by f1rank
```

Sorry, I don't have time to test/trouble shoot, but the logic should be there.